# nautilus crash when merging/overwriting files

Tags: 10.10, nautilus

On my Ubuntu 10.10, whenever I want to copy some files/folders over some other files/folders, or when I try to empty the trash, nautilus crashes!

Example:
I have a folder with some files. Now I want to overwrite this folder with a folder with the same name, same files, but some additional files, the merge window comes up, I choose merge and nautilus crashes (does not respond, when I press the close button I can force close it). Some times it even does the copying/emptying (trash), but it always crashes!

This happens when copying to the same partition/ntfs partition/netshares, but not when I make a new folder and copy the files/folders into that (without overwriting anything). On a netshare, it's even possible to merge these files afterwards with another computer!

dmesg/syslog/messages does not show any entry related to that problem.

Does anyone have a solution for this very annoying problem?

EDIT:

> [dpkg -l nautilus*](http://pastebin.com/AT0ZDavK) (see output in pastebin)

EDIT2:
I found out, nautilus already crashes before clicking replace/merge (as soon as the question appeares. In the video it's not entirely clear, that i click the cross before the force-close dialog appeares.

- [Video of problem](http://videobin.org/+2jx/2ul.html)
- [nautilus-debug-log.txt](http://pastebin.com/KWkyedkS)

EDIT3:
Filed bugreport: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/678233

**SOLUTION**

The problem was rabbitvcs, installing version 0.14.1.1 solved the problem!

Comment: are you using nautilus-elementary by any chance?

Comment: no, see edit for details

Comment: Is the nautilus-debug-log file one that nautilus spontaneously dumped or did you need to request it? I can't seem to find anything out of the ordinary in it.

Comment: I requested it, ther is no spontaneous log file

Comment: Very nice bug report!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, in all probability, a [legitimate bug](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/report-problem). You should file a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus).

Nautilus, should it crash, will write a file called "nautilus-debug-log.txt" to your home directory. If it isn't there, you can use this:

```
kill -SIGUSR1 `pidof nautilus`
```

to force nautilus to write it (note: this doesn't *kill* nautilus). This file contains very helpful information to be [included](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) in your bug report. Also, you should include all the steps (in detail) to reproduce the problem.

Read the [Bug Reporting Tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) if you're reporting a bug for the first time.

Comment: I posted additional material. If anyone can give me some additional infos plz do so now. If not I'll file a bug report.

Comment: You should not hesitate all that much with a bug report, they are important – even if they may, after some digging, turn out to be invalid or whatever. Bug reports are a great way to contribute to making ubuntu better, as long, of course, as they are as well researched as yours is going to be, with the material you've posted so far.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a problem from RabbitVCS:
http://code.google.com/p/rabbitvcs/issues/detail?id=476

Comment: thx, I just found this out myself, I will add the solution to the question.